# Looking for a more pythonic logical solution

Tags: python, logic

I was doing some practice problems in [Coding Bat](http://codingbat.com/python), and came across this one..

```
Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if one of the values is the same as another of the values, it does not count towards the sum. 

lone_sum(1, 2, 3) → 6
lone_sum(3, 2, 3) → 2
lone_sum(3, 3, 3) → 0
```

My solution was the following.

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):
   sum = a+b+c
   if a == b:
     if a == c:
         sum -= 3 * a
     else:
         sum -= 2 * a
   elif b == c:
     sum -= 2 * b
   elif a == c:
     sum -= 2 * a
   return sum
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Regarding code indentation, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Or, click the ? icon at the top of the edit box.

Comment: @mhawke: I followed the 4 spaces indent alright, but in preview it none of the additional indents showed, so got a little confused. Thanks for editing the code!

Comment: please thank Martin for the clean up!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
def lone_sum(*args):
      return sum(v for v in args if args.count(v) == 1)
```

Comment: For only three arguments this implementation might be fine, but it shouldn't be used for larger number of arguments since it is O(n²).  And it completely eludes me why "without any imports" should be considered an advantage by itself.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: You may be right but it's the perfect answer to OP's question.

Comment: @BandGap: I like Niklas' answer best.  It's just as short, just as readable and O(n).

Answer (score 13):

Another possibility that works for an arbitrary number of arguments:

```
from collections import Counter

def lone_sum(*args):
    return sum(x for x, c in Counter(args).items() if c == 1)
```

Note that in Python 2, you should use `iteritems` to avoid building a temporary list.

Comment: It is worth noting that Counter is only available in Python >= 2.7

Comment: @Daniel: Python 2.7 should be the standard by now, I usually assume it to be available. If `Counter` is not available, you can easily build an equivalent version using a `defaultdict(int)`

Comment: @NiklasB., I would venture to guess that a lot of Apple users are still running 2.6 or lower. Apple has only just upgraded to 2.7 with OSX 10.7.

Comment: Current Debian stable doesn't include 2.7, and there are many environments with even older version of Python.  Most GAE applications still run on 2.5.  Many HPC clusters I encountered only support 2.5.  Simply claiming "Python 2.7 should be the standard by now" doesn't match reality to well.

Comment: @Sven: Yeah, maybe that's not the case. Still, there exist several pure-Python implementations of `collections.Counter` that can be used instead if it's not natively available.

Answer (score 8):

A more general solution for any number of arguments is

```
def lone_sum(*args):
    seen = set()
    summands = set()
    for x in args:
        if x not in seen:
            summands.add(x)
            seen.add(x)
        else:
            summands.discard(x)
    return sum(summands)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for `lone_sum(3, 3, 3)`; you need to add a check before removing from summands.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma: There has been a version with this problem for a minute or so, but the current version is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Could use a defaultdict to screen out any elements appearing more than once.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def lone_sum(*args):
  d = defaultdict(int)
  for x in args:
    d[x] += 1

  return sum( val for val, apps in d.iteritems() if apps == 1 )
```

Comment: This is similar in spirit to the approach taken by Niklas B - his is also more concise.

Comment: Also start using 4 space indenting in Python! See PEP-8 for a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):
    z = (a,b,c)
    x = []
    for item in z:
        if z.count(item)==1:
            x.append(item)
    return sum(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had a very similar approach to what you had:

```
def lone_sum(a, b, c):

  if a != b and b != c and c != a:
    return a + b + c

  elif a == b == c:
    return 0 

  elif a == b:
    return c
  elif b == c:
    return a
  elif c == a:
    return b
```

Since if 2 values are the same the code will automatically return the
remaining value.

Answer (score -1):

I tried this on Codingbat but it doesn`t work, although it does on the code editor.

def lone_sum(a, b, c):
  s = set([a,b,c])
  return sum(s)